# Filtering based on data in excel

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

I was given an excel file with account numbers in them and told to write a query that returns the account numbers in the list that meet a certain criteria. While I was able to write the query in general without problems I don't know how to reference the excel document in the query. I worked around it by copy and pasting the account numbers into a

`WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER IN (...)`

The problem is that the amount of account numbers I had was over 6000 while the max numbers in a `IN` list is 1000. I ended up doing it piecewise but there must be a better way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Developer to (create the table and) load the data into a table.

From there, use a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table and insert the values into that, which you can join to from your query.